# What does IsDBNull(int) method do?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have many users in a MySQL table  in a WinForms app. The user enters their username and password. My question is how can I check if there is a user with that username and password in the table in the database? Can I accomplish this with the `IsDBNull()` method? I asked in other sites on the following link:
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.isdbnull?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_IsDBNull_System_Object_)
, but  could not get an adequate answer there.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you not know how to query things with SQL?  What do you think `IsDBNull()` would do for you?

Comment: You call the database with a `SELECT` statement and just look at the results. `IsDBNull()` is a method which checks if the given input does not have a value. For example, if a `nullable` database column is empty/null.

Comment: `SELECT 1 FROM TblUser WHERE Username=@username AND Password=@password`. Then use `MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader` and check it's [`HasRows`](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataReader~HasRows.html) property

Answer (score 1):

`IsDBNull(int)` method checks if a specific index you are reading from the database is null.

For example if your query was:

```
select 1,null;
```

`IsDBNull(0)` would have returned `false` (since the first field is `1`) while `IsDBNull(1)` would have returned `true` (since it returns a `NULL`).

Note: It's also best practice to use this as a safety check before reading values from nullable columns.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as asked...

I'm assuming you mean a MySQL version of SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32) ([IsDbNull(int) docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull)).  It does what those docs say.

If you are reading a record from a data reader (something that implements `IDataReader`) you can test if a particular field (/column) value is NULL by using 'IsDbNull(zeroIndexedColumnNumber)`

It's not much use for checking "that [the] username and password [are] in the table in the database".  For that, use the suggestion from @TimSchemlter:

```
SELECT 1 FROM TblUser WHERE Username=@username AND Password=@password.
```

Then use MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader and check it's HasRows property